# Uploading multiple images to Imgur through their API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imgur

Alright just to get this out of the way, PHP is not an option, since this project's code has to be accessible to view through browsers via chrome's page source and inspector and all that.
I'm trying to upload multiple images at once (through HTML's input=file) and I'm having a bit of trouble.
I was provided with a code that is supposed to work with only one file, and it does, but when implementing it into a for loop it doesn't work as expected, it only uploads the first image and then gives the response of that and only that.

```
var files = $("#upload").get(0).files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i]) {
        var apiUrl = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image';
        var apiKey = '<apiKey>';
        var settings = {
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl,
            headers: {
            Authorization: 'Client-ID ' + apiKey,
            Accept: 'application/json'
            },
            mimeType: 'multipart/form-data'
        };
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", files[i]);
        settings.data = formData;

        var urlObj = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
        $("#sortable").html("");
        $("#sortable").append("<img src='" + urlObj + "' id='" + (i + 1) + "' class='unuploaded ui-state-default'>");

        // Response contains stringified JSON
        // Image URL available at response.data.link
        $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
            $("#" + (i+1)).src = response.data.link;
            $("#" + (i+1)).removeClass("unuploaded");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I re read it, comment deleted even before you wrote yours. `$("#sortable").html("");` clears your output area every time, so that's probably why you only see one response. Did you check your developer tools to see if the uploads were actually happening? P.s. synchronous Ajax is deprecated and considered a poor practice

Comment: Oh alright, well that's embarrassing. I meant to put that line of code before the loop so it can clear any forced input via inspector by the user, but I accidentally put it inside. It's weird that it gave me the response of the first image though, and not the last as it should have, but oh well. Hmmm, could you provide me a reason why? Or a link that says it. I'll make the asynchronized value true anyway but just curious.

Comment: It's not obvious to me just from the code why that's happening to be honest. Perhaps you could step through it with the debugger if you're curious.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your time.